# Proving compactness of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I'm having a hard time finding a solution for the following problem:

Prove that the operator $ T \in \mathcal{L}(\ell_2) $ defined with the formula
$$ T((x_1, x_2, \dots, )) = (0, x_1, x_2/2, x_3/3, \dots) $$

is compact.

That's the trouble I'm having with functional analysis - how do I ever know how to approach a problem like this? I'm supposed to show that $T$ turns bounded sets into relatively compact sets (it's enough that it does so for a unit ball). However I can't seem to find a way to solve that

Comment: You can use ideas from this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320751/trying-to-prove-that-operator-is-compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $T_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n {1 \over k} x_k e_{k+1}$. $T_n$ has finite rank, so it is compact.

We have $\|T-T_n\| \le {1 \over n+1}$, hence $T_n \to T$ and so $T$ is compact.

Comment: Since I was not sure about your last statement, let me refer to one of your different answers: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/416046/how-to-show-that-the-norm-limit-of-compact-operators-is-compact

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1: Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You might show the image of the unit ball is totally bounded. Given $\epsilon > 0$, take $N$ large enough, and cover the projection of the image  of the unit ball onto the first $N$ coordinates by small balls ...